# How do I do right clicks on iBook G4?

Tags: 10.04, mouse, mac, apple

I can't figure out how I allow my iBook to right click in Ubuntu. It's one big button; so, I used to hold Option and click. I'm willing to do that, but I can't figure out how. Unless, of course, I've completely let the noob out and one doesn't right click in Ubuntu.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I found it.

You need to edit the scrip that they talk about her to mimic right clicking, not middle clicking. Here are the steps.

1. Install mouseemu:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mouseemu
   ```
2. edit the `/etc/default/mouseemu` file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/mouseemu
   ```
3. Then add this to the file:

   ```
   RIGHT_CLICK="-right 125 272"      # Left Apple Key (LEFTMETA) + click
   ```
4. Do everything else the same as the forum post.

I hope this helps folks.

Reference: [Ubuntu Forums: i can't right click](http://ubuntu-virginia.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1437770)

Answer (score 2):

There are [instructions in Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook4-1/Lucid) (see topic "Trackpad").

Basically, you can map right click to two finger click by modifying system preferences and `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-synaptics.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "synaptics"

    Option "FingerLow" "10"
    Option "FingerHigh" "20"
EndSection
```

> To achieve familiar behavior with the Apple trackpad go to System -> Preferences -> Mouse and select the Touchpad tab. Select Disable touchpad while typing. Deselect Enable mouse clicks with touchpad. Select Two-finger scrolling.

(quote from wiki)

Comment: That would work for a MacBook, but I'm looking for an iBook G4, which was before synaptic, two-finger clicking. To right-click on the Mac OS X, one had to press Option and then click.

Comment: Oh crap. My bad. Another option: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook3-1/Intrepid?action=show&redirect=MacBook3-1 (section "Middle&Right Click with Left&Right Cmd Keys"). It's for Intrepid, but you could try it with newer Ubuntu too.

Comment: Nope...that's for an even new laptop. MacBook is before iBook.

Comment: @user11694: yes, I know that. However, most probably keycodes for control buttons are same for MacBook and iBook.

Answer (score 0):

By default (with Lubuntu 12.04 on the iBook G4 I am currently using), middle-click is mapped on F11, and right-click on F12.

I can also do a right-click by making a "two-finger tap" on the touchpad.

Comment: With Lubuntu 16.04 freshly installed on an iBook G4, the two-finger tap doesn't work by default.